# How select text in TextInput in react native for andorid?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I select all text in the TextInput field when I click on this field, i.e. the onFocus action?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `selectTextOnFocus` as a prop with `TextInput`. This will ensure that all `text` inside the `TextInput` is `highlighted` when the field is focused.

`<TextInput ref={input => this.myInput = input} selectTextOnFocus style={{height: 100, width: 100}} defaultValue='Hey there' />`

Usage to focus the `TextInput`:
`this.myInput.focus()`

---

More Information : https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#selecttextonfocus

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selection prop of TextInput

```
<TextInput 
  value={'aaaa'}
  onFocus={onFocus}
  selection={{
    start: 0,
    end: 4,
  }}
/>
```

You can modify the start and end value onFocus.
Reference: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#selection